# Validate XHTML frameset

Tags: xhtml

I am trying to validate my XHTML Frameset page but I get the following errors from the W3C Markup Validation Service:

```
Missing "charset" attribute for "text/xml" document.
Line 1, Column 41: parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected
```

I have the following heading in my file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" charset=utf-8?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the heading as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
```

I added the following **meta** tag in between the **head** tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

No more errors or warnings.

Comment: If you mean you removed the xml prolog, yes. It had an error: no quotes around the value for the `charset` attribute. All attribute values must be quoted! In addition, there is no `charset` attribute defined for the prolog. Using just the `encoding` part should have done it.

Comment: That isn't XHTML, that's HTML. Remove the meta element, it's completely irrelevant. Keep the XML declaration, you need it to define the encoding correctly.